# Trouble with Lubuntu 15.10 after cold boot

Tags: boot, kernel, lubuntu

Recently, i have started having trouble with booting Lubuntu. After turning on, i have to restart computer 5-8 times to successfully boot. Here is what is happening on each start: first, i get black screen instead of boot screen, after i restart, it automatically restarts again when it comes to booting. After that, kernel panic (init process killed). Next start - bunch of errors (noticed 'seg fault' appearing the most). Restart again, it gets to desktop screen, then freezes completely after 5 seconds. After another reset, it is working, but sometimes it freezes again (doesn't matter of what i do).

I checked kernel log file in /var/log, last message is 4 days old, no errors as i could see.

I think this started happening after kernel update from 4.2.0-19 to 4.2.0-22-generic, but not sure. Don't know what to try do diagnose the problem, because i am linux noob.

Comment: It's probably a kernel error. Try booting with the old kernel (in the advanced options tab under GRUB menu) and purging the new kernel (be VERY careful and remove only the right kernel). You should run in a terminal, after that: `sudo update-initramfs -u && sudo update-grub`.

Comment: @EduardoCola I deleted old kernels because i didn't have free space on /boot partition. :/

Comment: Well, that's bad. Always keep your current kernel and the previous one, otherwise you may get in situations like this. And I always recommend people to have only one partition, since multiple partitions often leave them with "no enough space" errors.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind next time i install ubuntu. Thanks.